# How to put a Text between TextInput lines?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a custom component made up of a Text above a TextInput that word wraps together. The effect I'm trying to achieve is having a Text between each line of a TextInput so that when something is entered in the TextInput, something is shown directly above it in the Text. It's important that the lines between the TextInput are not editable. Any idea how to do this?
[I included a picture to better explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3V5z.png) The top image is the behaviour I'm trying to get and the bottom is how it should look.

Answer (score 0):

if I am getting your question right then  [this is your solution](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168)

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             >
            >
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"

                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

In your project's build.gradle file, add the following lines in the project's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

}

Comment: I added a picture to better explain.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom component that stores an array of Strings (the user's input) in the state.
In the render function, you could iterate over the array and render one Text and one TextInput for each item.
You would disable editing of all TextInputs except for the last one so that it appears that they can edit at the end of the input. When that TextInput will be forced to wrap, then you could add a new entry to the state String array. It will be pretty convoluted, but hopefully thats a starting point for you

Comment: Thanks. You gave me an idea I would like to try out. I'm thinking of taking advantage of onContentSizeChange/onLayout to figure out when they need to wrap and do the rest of what you said. I'll let you know how it goes.